# Inaccurate search result from Google place API (Geocoding)

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

i am trying to geocode some addresses in the Philippines but when I do my search through the Google APIs, I only get very inaccurate results (10kms away from the point I am looking for while maps.google.com provides much better results with approximately few hundred meters error).

After reading other posts here (and testing both Google Maps API and Google Places API), it seems that maps.google.com is based on Google Place so that should be the option to implement... However, I still get a list of places that are not really near by the address I am looking for.

My call look like this:

```
address="Balay Expo Centro Building, EDSA corner McArthur Avenue, Araneta Center, Cubao, Quezon City, Metro Manila, Philippines"
google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location = address,
    radius=5)

for place in query_result.places:
    print place.name
    print place.geo_location
```

Does anyone know how to increase the precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use web service api? If the web service api it's more precise you can use a json-parser in your application.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) when you should be using [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests). I'm linking the Places API web service guide here because it explains the difference between these two kinds of search.

Since you seem to be using [python-google-places](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/blob/master/googleplaces/__init__.py), this is how (I think) it works:

```
address = "Balay Expo Centro Building, EDSA corner McArthur Avenue, Araneta Center, Cubao"
user_location = "14.617766,121.057154"  # Cubao
google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)
query_result = googlemaps.places(
    query = address,
    lat_lng = user_location,
    radius=500)
```

Actually, `lat_lng` and `radius` are optional, but results are likely to be better if they are set to sensible values to reflect where the user is.